# Ubuntu Server 22.04.2 LTS Autoinstall fails during Packer build on Hyper-V

Tags: system-installation

I'm trying to use HashiCorp Packer to autoinstall Ubuntu Server 22.04.2 LTS (note the `.2` at the end). I found a repository on GitHub that had an allegedly working Packer build for the 22.04.0 build, but after I updated to 22.04.2, the build started failing.

The boot command is as follows:

```
<wait3>c<wait3>","linux /casper/vmlinuz quiet autoinstall net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0 ip=dhcp ipv6.disable=1 ds='nocloud-net;s=http://{{ .HTTPIP }}:{{ .HTTPPort }}/' <enter>","initrd /casper/initrd <enter>","boot <enter>
```

The last thing I see in the VM output is:

```
Repeat this process for the rest of the CDs in your set.
no search or nameservers found in /run/net-eth0.conf /run/net-*.conf /run/net6-*.conf
```

What can I do to get the autoinstall command working, and avoid this DNS nameservers error? I'm using the official ISO from `https://releases.ubuntu.com/22.04.2/ubuntu-22.04.2-live-server-amd64.iso`, not a custom ISO of any sort.

[image]

Comment: What happens if you remove the `ip=dhcp` kernel argument from your boot command?  I see that screen with that kernel argument, although the boot process does eventually continue.  Without that kernel argument I do not see any of that output.